# How to set memory limit for Java 11 inside Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, production-environment, java-11

What is the process to set memory limit for Java 11 inside Docker?

Which JDK to use for production environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As java 11 (10+) can automatically detect the container's memory you can [set memory limit](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory) on your container and it should WAI:

```
docker run -m 512 ....
```

2. As for the choice of JDK, you can either use [oracle JDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-jdk) which is licensed or open source [OpenJDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk).

More details in this article: https://www.docker.com/blog/improved-docker-container-integration-with-java-10/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I would like to know how  java 11 (10+) can automatically detect the container's memory?
Thanks

Comment: Basically any program can query the cgroups they are running in and detect how much memory limit it has. It's typically mounted under: `/sys/fs/cgroup`. more info `man 7 cgroups`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum heap size using the hotspot JVM `-Xmx` option (see [java 11 options](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE))

You may use [AdoptOpenJDK](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11) for production as they are kept up tp date.